# scroll is not been displayed after a grid kendo ui is been populated

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo ui grid populated from a datasource ajax call.

```
<div id="my-grid">
  <div kendo-grid="myGrid">
       k-options="myGridConfig"></div>
   </div>
 </div>

# myController

this.myGridConfig = {
  dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read:     '/api/endpoing',
                    dataType: 'json'
                }
```

The grid is been populated correctly but when it does the browsers scroll is not been displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't valid markup.  It appears you have a div within a div within a div...why?  Are you applying any other styles to the grid that may eliminate the scrollbar?  Can you provide a screenshot?  You can try adding *scrollable: true* when instantiating the grid widget.